# Should I store constructor argument by value or by pointer?

Tags: c++

Let's say I'm writing a class that could be re-used in a variety of contexts. Its constructor accepts a user defined type that I store in a member variable. Even for objects that I know are cheap to copy, I'm trying to decide if it's better to take the argument by value or by pointer.

```
// By value
class MyType
{
private:
    SomeUdt udt_;

public:
    MyType(SomeUdt udt) :
        udt_ {udt}
    {}

    // ...
};
```

vs

```
// By pointer
class MyType
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<SomeUdt> udt_;

public:
    MyType(std::shared_ptr<SomeUdt> udt) :
        udt_ {udt}
    {}

    // ...
};
```

If I take it by (shared) pointer, then I'm almost certainly forcing the client to allocate that object on the heap. (*Technically* they could allocate on the stack and still send me a pointer, but that would muddy ownership and lifetime.)

And if I take it by value, then I remove their ability to manage instances, such as if the client wanted SomeUdt to be a singleton.

Which is the better default approach?

EDIT:

A couple other interesting points in this analysis.

First, a commenter mentioned that if I take by pointer, then my private data isn't entirely private. The client has access to my member object.

Also, if the user defined type needs to be polymorphic and has any pure virtual members, then I think you have no choice but to use pointers.

Comment: If you pass it as a pointer client could modify private variable through this pointer.

Comment: by value - then move it into place.

Comment: What's wrong with `template<class...Us> explicit MyType(Us&&...Vs) :udt_(std::forward<Us>(Vs)...) {}`  Is your container a template?    If it's a template, store by value, and the _client_ can instantiate with a pointer if that's what they want: `MyType<std::shared_ptr<SomeUdt>>`.  Why does it need this object anyway?

Comment: > Why does it need this object anyway? --
It could be for all sorts of reasons. Maybe MyType needs a logger object, or cache object, or a proxy, or a factory, or whatever. Templates would probably give the client the most freedom. The trade-off is I lose the separate translation units.

Answer (score 2):

The two approaches have different semantics:

1. Taking a `SomeUdt` says "I want the value of a `SomeUdt`."

   In this case, the client code can produce the value however it likes - perhaps from a temporary object, or automatically allocated, or dynamically allocated. It doesn't matter because it's not the source object that's important, but the *value*. Once the value has been provided, the client and `MyType` don't share any state.
2. Taking a `std::shared_ptr<SomeUdt>` says "I want to share ownership of a dynamically allocated `SomeUdt` object."

   In this case, the client code would be expected to dynamically allocate a `SomeUdt` object, manage its lifetime with a `shared_ptr`, and then share ownership of that object with `MyType`. Once the object has been provided, the client and `MyType` share some state.

Unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, you should prefer to pass objects by value. Value semantics and local state are always good things. You should use the `shared_ptr` only if the shared ownership semantics are required.

Remember that if `SomeUdt` type is moveable, it will be more efficient to do:

```
MyType(SomeUdt udt) :
    udt_ {std::move(udt)}
{}
```

> And if I take it by value, then I remove their ability to manage instances, such as if the client wanted SomeUdt to be a singleton.

How `MyType` stores its state is its own business. Why should the client code care? It should be encapsulated by `MyType`.

> Also, if the user defined type needs to be polymorphic and has any pure virtual members, then I think you have no choice but to use pointers.

If you want polymorphism, then you inherently cannot ask for the value of an object because you don't know what the type of that value will be. In that case, I would suggest taking a `SomeUdt&` or `SomeUdt const&` (assuming `SomeUdt` is the base class). This then says "I need a `SomeUdt` object" and makes no requests about how that object was created.

Taking a `shared_ptr` is purely for sharing ownership of dynamically allocated objects. It makes assumptions about the object being shared.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a good reason for something else, prefer this approach:

```
// By value, using move
class MyType
{
private:
    SomeUdt udt_;

public:
    MyType(SomeUdt udt) :
        udt_ { std::move(udt) }
    {}

    // ...
};
```

Comment: I recommend splitting into const-ref and r-ref overloads when you have a single argument, to optimize non-movable types.

Comment: `std::array<double, 32>`?

Comment: By all means write optimised solutions for pessimistic corner cases. The general case does not warrant it, nor would the vast majority of this corner case.

Comment: You don't agree?  Fair enough.  I tend to prematurely optimize.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are doing modify operations on the data then it is better to go by value. 
If your class just acts like a container/reader then by reference is ideal.